# jQuery complete replace DOM of element with another DOM - faster way?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dom

I'm using jQuery's AJAX for getting new content from server. Data is loaded in JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
        'ajax': '1',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: somefunction
});
```

For server-side application limitation, I'm not able to setup more JSON variables inside so I have to load everything into content. That is why I have to load result into jQuery, than search and replace some elements on page, like this (used in `somefunction`):

```
var somefunction = function(data) {
    var con = $('<div></div>').html(data.content); // just $(data.content) is not working
    $('div#mainContent').html(con.find('div#ajax-content').html());
    ... // same process with three more divs
}
```

**EDIT: Please, note that I have to do same process to replace three divs!**

There is more about that, but as example, it's enough I hope. My question: For some logic way, I expect that loading result into DOM (`$(data.content)`), parsing to html (`con.find('dix#ajax-content').html()`) and back to DOM (`$('div#mainContent').html()`) seems to me like loosing some resources and decreasing the perfomance so I would like to know if there is any faster way to do it and load DOM directly, like:

```
$('div#mainContent').dom(con.find('div#ajax-content').dom());
```

I tried to google it but maybe I don't know what to type in. Also jQuery documentation does not helped me a lot.

Some facts:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQuery UI 1.10.3 available

Finally, I know that it would be much more better to do something with server-side app to provide more JSON variables, however, I need to write not-so-easy peace of code which is requiring longer time to develop which I don't have right now. Doing it on client side would be temporary solution for now, however, I don't want to decrease performace a lot.

Side-question:

is it correct to use `find()` function in this case or there is any better one?

**EDIT 2 (not working parsing string)**
I'm expecting this working but it's not:

```
content = '<div id="ajax-title">Pečivo běžné, sladké, slané</div>
<div id="ajax-whereami"><a href="/category/4">Chléba a pečivo</a> » Pečivo běžné, sladké, slané</div>';
$(content);
```

Comment: try data.content.toString()

Comment: @BASarat I assumed data.content is a string.

Comment: @BASarat Than I cannot parse it and find content of specific div in the request. `data.content` is string anyway. And it does not help for line marked "does not work".

Comment: @tomis if all things need to replace elements that are in $('div#mainContent') than you should cache that: $content=$('div#mainContent'); $content.find("something").replaceWith(con.find("somethingElse");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `$(data.content)` should work just fine, but you have to keep in mind that **the top level elements can only be reached via `.filter()`** instead of `.find()`. If the elements you wish to target are at least one level deeper than the root you should use `.find()` though; in the examples below you can replace `.filter()` with `.find()` where appropriate.

```
var $con = $(data.content);
$('div#mainContent')
  .empty()
  .append($con.filter('div#ajax-content'))
  .append($con.filter('div#another-id'))
  .append($con.filter('div#and-another-id'));
```

You can also combine the selectors together:

```
  .append($con.filter('div#ajax-content, div#another-id, div#and-another-id'));
```

Lastly, since identifiers should only appear once inside a document, you can drop the `div` part:

```
  .append($con.filter('#ajax-content, #another-id, #and-another-id'));
```

**Update**

Okay, it seems that jQuery doesn't evaluate `data.content` properly when there are newlines in the wrong places; this should work in all cases:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = data.content;

var $con = $(wrapper);
```

Comment: Please, look at my sec. edit as `$(data.content)` really don't work.

Comment: @tomis You didn't read my answer properly; it works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/iluvus/1/) using `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

Comment: no, problem is in parsing but I have found it out: there are line breaks which are broking that. Removing line breaks, it works normally.

Comment: @tomis Yeah, or adding backslash at the end of the lines, but the more preferred way is using `+` to append multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah... Thinking how to solve this :-) Thanks anyway for help.

Comment: @tomis I've updated my answer a bit to show when to use `.find()` and `.filter()`. Also, if the response comes straight from the server you don't have to worry about line endings messing up the parsing. Do let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: @tomis The problem here is *not* the string endings; if the response comes from the server in `content.data`, there should be no need to manipulate it; this is only a problem when you're manually testing it.

Comment: Actually, replacing I have solved - please, see HMR`s answer and comments - by replaceWith answer. But your answer helped me with make string to be parsed and by using `.filter`... Both answers helped me :-); be sure that I have tested in console, as well in normal browsing by getting it from server... Both same results.

Comment: @tomis `.replaceWith()` assumes there's content inside `#mainContent` already; not sure if that will always be true and it wasn't clear from the question either. Nonetheless, my answer should work as well; it clears the contents and then appends whatever comes from the server and after filtering.

Comment: There will be always content. Final working solution is: `var con = $(data.content.replace(/\n/, '')); $('div#mainContent').replaceWith(con.find('div#mainContent');`

Comment: @tomis That `.replace()` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30289/discussion-between-tomis-and-jack)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it this will help:

```
$('div#mainContent').replaceWith(con.find('div#ajax-content'))
 .attr("id","mainContent")
```

Now you don't have to set the html of the element and get the html of the Element you just created from JSON. Not sure if this actually is faster but it does skip the 2 html() steps.

Comment: Hey, that might help... I'm able to replace ids comming in request so it will be easier than it looks: `$('div#mainContent').replaceWith(con.find('div#mainContent'));` Will it work? Is it valid? (I'm stupid man that I did not find it by myself).

Comment: According to the documentation it should work. replaceWith takes a string, element or jquery object as an argument. http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: that will save also one `.find()` function from my script. Will try, if it will work, your answer is candidate to accept answer (just maybe some edit would be fine for future visitors :-) ).

Comment: @tomis looking back I see that I've missed something, I thought you had to replace several elements inside #mainContent but you're looking to replace #mainContent. In that case you can take out the .find part and re set the id using .attr. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.load`, although I believe it is essentially just a wrapper for the same thing:

```
$("#mainContent").load(url + " #ajax-content", data);
```

You can increase performance on the server side by sending only the specific ajax content (less to download and parse) although that may be difficult.

Other than that, your best bet is to use vanilla JS over jQuery, at least for the appending (using `innerHTML` directly).

Comment: Maybe, you will correct me, but I can't handle error states when using  `.load()`, can I? Unlikely, I have to replace content of 3 divs placed complete on different places, as well the page title (this is quite simple). Three requests is not acceptable (innerHTML solution, load solution). But thanks anyway.

Comment: @tomis you can still do `innerHTML` on three separate divs, it would just have to be in a loop

Comment: Does `.load()` clear the target element? I thought it only appends to it.

Comment: @Jack from doc, it seems it's replaced: (...) `.load()` sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data. (...)